# Is there a way to find out if Graphics were translated?

Tags: java, swing

Let's assume I have an object mainPanel  extending JPanel, and inside it another object internaPanel extending Jpanel.

In mainPanel's paintComponent() method I'm using translate() method on my Graphics object, which should also change the origin of my internaPanel graphic context. And it does, as long as I call repaint() method on my mainPanel when I need to. But the problem is, that sometimes my internaPanel is forced to repaint on its own - for example when I change its opaque parameter. When that happens, internaPanel obviously appears in wrong part of JFrame.

How can I prevent that from happening? Is there a way to check if Graphics parameter of internaPanel paintComponent() method came from mainPanel (and if it was translated)?

Thank you!

Comment: Please show some code!

Comment: ................code??

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you would be using the Graphics translate(...) method when you have a parent/child relationship between two components. Graphics translation is used when you are doing custom painting.

When you are dealing with Swing components you should probably be using a layout manager and let the layout manager invoke the `setLocation(...)` method on each component so the child is painted relative to the parent.

You should not attempt to manage the location yourself. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have code that changes your GUI object's state within a paintComponent method, and this you should never do, for the reason you've discovered: that you don't have full control over when or even if a painting will occur.

The solution is to change object state outside of paintComponent, and then use that state (field) within paintComponent.

For more details, show more (some!) code.